# Unable to locate ILoadBalancer for service while using Ribbon with Eureka

Tags: spring-cloud

I'm using spring cloud verion 1.0.0.RC1. Getting an error 'Unable to locate ILoadBalancer for service'.

Any thoughts..is something missed. Isn't there a default load balancer used by ribbon.

**##########application.yml#############**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    client:
      serviceIds:
        - records

records:
  ribbon:
      listOfClients: http://VISERVER09:8761/eureka-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/eureka,http://VISERVER08:8761/eureka-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/eureka
```

**################ code using service############**#

```
String url = "http://records/ServiceB-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/records/{record}";
restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class, "1234");
```

**########## Log Output ##############**#

```
 --- BaseLoadBalancer: Client:records instantiated a LoadBalancer:DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=records,current list of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:null
--- ChainedDynamicProperty: Flipping property: records.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimitto use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
 --- DynamicServerListLoadBalancer: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer for client records initialized: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=records,current list of Servers=[VISERVER08:8181, VISERVER09:8181],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {defaultzone=[Zone:defaultzone; Instance count:2;       Active connections count: 0;    Circuit breaker tripped count: 0;       Active connections per server: 0.0;]
},Server stats: [[Server:VISERVER09:8181;     Zone:defaultZone;       Total Requests:0;       Successive connection failure:0;        Total blackout
 seconds:0;     Last connection made:Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 GMT 1970;      First connection made: Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 GMT 1970;    Active Connections:0;
total failure count in last (1000) msecs:0;     average resp time:0.0;  90 percentile resp time:0.0;    95 percentile resp time:0.0;    min resp time:
0.0;    max resp time:0.0;      stddev resp time:0.0]
, [Server:VISERVER08:8181;    Zone:defaultZone;       Total Requests:0;       Successive connection failure:0;        Total blackout seconds:0;
Last connection made:Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 GMT 1970;      First connection made: Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 GMT 1970;    Active Connections:0;   total failure
count in last (1000) msecs:0;   average resp time:0.0;  90 percentile resp time:0.0;    95 percentile resp time:0.0;    min resp time:0.0;      max re
sp time:0.0;    stddev resp time:0.0]
]}ServerList:DiscoveryEnabledNIWSServerList:; clientName:records; Effective vipAddresses:records; isSecure:false; datacenter:null

--- ConnectionPoolCleaner: Initializing ConnectionPoolCleaner for NFHttpClient:VISERVER08
 --- ConnectionPoolCleaner: Initializing ConnectionPoolCleaner for NFHttpClient:VISERVER08
--- [dispatcherServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to locate ILoadBalancer for service: VISERVER08] with root cause
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to locate ILoadBalancer for service: VISERVER08**
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.getServer(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:77)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:45)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonInterceptor.intercept(RibbonInterceptor.java:30)
        at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$RequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:84)
        at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:69)
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
```

Comment: It looks like you got 2 `RibbonInterceptors` in your `RestTemplate`. Where did it come from?

Comment: P.S. if you tidy up your post (use markdown) more people will read it.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. I added an interceptor for authorization instead of adding in the headers...now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you got 2 `RibbonInterceptors` in your `RestTemplate`. The second one is translating the physical hostname and getting nothing back from the service registry.